# How do I get gnash to play flash videos?

Tags: video

I've found quite a few postings that indicate that flash video (youtube or otherwise) will play in midori after installing these

sudo apt-get install gnash browser-plugin-gnash

However, all it does is just sit there thinking about playing video for as long as it can So far I think it's made it up to 3 hrs.

Current setup:

HDMI out,
Mouse (but no keyboard in USB),
Ethernet,
Good Power supply (Samsung charger),
wheezy 09 25 2013

Comment: There are other people trying this right?

Comment: Having the same problem... I will post if I resolve it somehow

Comment: I've all but given up. I think all the instructions out there are bogus.

Comment: After some updating it actually tries to play the video but it's more of a slideshow, so I am experimenting with omxplayer now. It seems to play youtube videos efficiently, but it has some browser integration problems. If I resolve them, perhaps I will post my code somewhere here.

Comment: If you've resolved this, please create a self-answer with what you did and mark it as such. We are attempting to get the Q:A ratio up and that would greatly help us out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use it.  It's not that secure and it is also heavy on the CPU. The pi wouldn't support it.  Finally, Adobe is getting mad at people for downloading it saying its spyware.

Comment: Quite mad that you had a downvote "-1" for this. Upvoted, and accepted answer. Gnash has to be spyware, only possible answer.